Uniformly coverging sequence of functions and differentiablity
Let $f_n:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a sequence of functions such that
each $f_n$ can be extended to an entire function $g_n: \mathbb C \rightarrow \mathbb C$.
Let
$$\Omega = \{ x + y i \in \mathbb C : x, y \in \mathbb R, |y| \le x^2, |x|\le 1\}.$$
Suppose that $g_n$ converges uniformly on $\Omega$.
Then it is easy to see that $f_n$ converges to a continuous function $f:[-1, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ on $[-1, 1]$
and $f$ is smooth on $(-1, 0) \cup (0, 1)$.
My question is:

Is $f$  differentiable (or even smooth)  at $0$?


In general, $f$ need not be differentiable at $0$. Let $h_1,h_2:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be two holomorphic functions that:

$h_1$ and $h_2$ are reflection symmetric, i.e., $\overline{h_1(\overline{z})} = h(z)$ and likewise for $h_2$,
$h_1(0) = h_2(0).$

Other than the criterion above, $h_1$ and $h_2$ may be chosen arbitrarily. Define $h:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that it is equal to $h_1$ on the left half-plane and equal to $h_2$ on the right half-plane. Note that $h$ by construction will be a function which is reflection symmetric, continuous on $\Omega$ (though not necessarily differentiable at $0$), and holomorphic on the interior $\Omega^\circ$.
Now we may apply Mergelyan's theorem to find a sequence of polynomials $\{p_n\}$ such that $p_n \rightarrow h$ uniformly on $\Omega$. Moreover, the polynomials may be taken to have real coefficients. Otherwise $\{\overline{p_n(\overline{z})}\}$ is another polynomial sequence which uniformly approaches $h$ and therefore so is $(p_n(z) + \overline{p_n(\overline{z})})/2$, which has real coefficients.
Now we may take $g_n = p_n$ to be the polynomials from above, and let $f_n$ be their restriction to the real axis. This constructs a sequence of real valued polynomials that converges uniformly on $\Omega$ with the limit $h$ potentially non-differentiable at $0$.
